# How to merge two ArrayLists without duplicates?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two arrayLists

```
ArrayList one = {A, B, C, D, E}
ArrayList two = {B, D, F, G}
```

I want to have my final ArrayList which will have **All** the elements of one and the elements which are only in two and not in one.

So 
ArrayList final = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G}.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is using a `Set` possible? This requires that your items in list one are unique.

Comment: I am not familiar with Set. So i dont prefer using it. And I am having  Java 1.2 in my device.

Comment: Lack of familiarity is no reason to shun an excellent data type. `Set` is available in 1.2. The question you must answer is: do you want *any* duplicates in your final list/set?

Comment: @DuncanJones No i dont want any duplicates in my final list/set. Could you point me on how to do this with Set

Comment: At least [one of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16520227/474189) already shows you how to do this.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
for (Object x : two){
   if (!one.contains(x))
      one.add(x);
}
```

assuming you don't want to use the set suggested in the comment. If you are looking for something fancier than this please clarify your question.

Comment: For each not supported in java version 1.2 or 1.4. My device is running java 1.2.

Comment: so don't use a for each and use a for instead

Comment: Ya.. thats what i tried. But i was just wondering if there is any better way or is this the best way..

Comment: If you want to stick with a `List` this is a perfectly acceptable way of doing it. Depending on the size of you data set a `Set` or `SortedList` might give you better performance even if you have to then copy back to a `List`

Comment: @JohnB ur solution is O(n^2) right?

Comment: @ueg1990 that looks about right. A `Set` is a better option here as I state.

Answer (score 75):

Either:

```
Set<Foo> fooSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(one);
fooSet.addAll(two);
List<Foo> finalFoo = new ArrayList<>(fooSet);
```

or

```
List<Foo> twoCopy = new ArrayList<>(two);
twoCopy.removeAll(one);
one.addAll(twoCopy);
```

Comment: However, the OP is using Java 1.2 so a re-write to remove generics may be better.

Comment: For the second solution, why should we create a twoCopy? Can we just one.removeAll(two); one.addAll(two): ?

Comment: You need the copy only if you don't want to modify the original two list. Regarding the second question: the order of the elements wouldn't be the same.

Comment: @CongWang In case you don't need the original `two` list. You can `two.removeAll(one); one.addAll(two)`

Answer (score 4):

Try this kind of thing. As `Set` doesn't allow duplicates you can add only the changes

```
ArrayList<String> a=new ArrayList<>();
a.add("a");
a.add("b");
ArrayList<String> b=new ArrayList<>();
a.add("a");
a.add("c");
Set<String> s=new HashSet<String>();
s.addAll(a);
s.addAll(b);
a=new ArrayList<>(s);
for(String r:a){
    System.out.println(r);
}
```

Comment: Your code snippet is unnecessarily large. Assume we know how to package it into a `main` and where to find normal imports. Just include the code.

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like this:

```
ArrayList<Object> result = new ArrayList<>();
result.addAll(one);

for(Object e: two){
    if(!result.contains(e))
        result.add(e);
}
```

Comment: You need to initialize `result`. You could just do `ArrayList result =  new ArrayList(one);` instead of the first loop.

Comment: @Keppil well its not the exact code anyway, arraylist is supposed to be generic, i was just giving an idea

Comment: @ay89 OP is using Java 1.2, so no generics.