# How to merge/aggregate two java objects having List<customType> as one member?

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I combine contents of two java objects into one? If contents are same then they should overwrite and if contents are different then new ones should get updated. e.g. I have following schema:

```
class A {
String id;
String response;
List<XYZ> slots;
}
```

XYZ further contains some data and Lists again. Now if I get two different objects of A which has different values of slots in it. How can I combine them into one? i.e. making it union but duplicates are not allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two ArrayLists without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520046/how-to-merge-two-arraylists-without-duplicates)

Answer (score 0):

in XYZ class, you can override equals method with your own logic to compare two XYZ objects.

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj instanceof XYZ)
        {
            XYZ objXYZ = (XYZ) obj;
            //here u can write your own logic to compare two XYZ objects and return true if satisfied else return false
            return this.id == objXYZ.id;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

then you can check the list using contains method while adding it to the list.

```
if(!slots.contains(newXYZ))
    slots.add(newXYZ)
```