# ANDROID how to filter a list base on another list in kotlin/java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have two lists:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

list_2 = [1, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

I want to get a list like this:

```
list_3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

No need to sort in ascending order, Thanks.

Comment: From your example it seems you want a disjoint union, case in which convert to set, merge, convert back to list.

Comment: yes. i want like you said.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge two ArrayLists without duplicates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520046/how-to-merge-two-arraylists-without-duplicates)

Comment: `val list_3 = (list_1 + list_2).distinct()`

Comment: thanks pro. I did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this following by using `union` operator

```
fun temp()
{
    val firstList = arrayListOf(1,2,3,4,5)
    val secondList = arrayListOf(1,3,5,6,7)
    val finalList = firstList.union(secondList)
    println("First list : ${firstList}")
    println("Second list : ${secondList}")
    println("Final list : ${finalList}")
}
```

In`secondList` contains common elements `1,3 and 5` as the `firstList`, It was removed in the `finalList`. You can also use `distinct` operator according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want entries from both lists, but they must appear only once.  I assume from your last statement that the order does not matter.  In that case this would be perfect for a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).  A [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is a [Collection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), so you can iterate through all the elements just as, for example, with a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

**EDIT**

Code snippets:

```
Integer[] a = {1,2,3};
Integer[] b = {2,3,4};

Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();

s.addAll(Arrays.asList(a));
s.addAll(Arrays.asList(b));

for (int i : s) {
    System.out.print(i + ", ");
}
System.out.println();
```

If your integers are already in a primitive array:

```
int[] c = {1,2,3};
int[] d = {2,3,4};

Set<Integer> S = new HashSet<>();

S.addAll(Arrays.asList(Arrays.stream(c).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new)));
S.addAll(Arrays.asList(Arrays.stream(d).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new)));

for (int i : S) {
    System.out.print(i + ", ");
}
System.out.println();
```

For both of these the output is:

```
1, 2, 3, 4,
```