# Merge Two List which have different size, In one with stream api on certain conditions

Tags: java, steam

Suppose I have two list which i want to get merged into one

**Merge Condition :
compare with id**

```
Case 1 : 
List 1 = [{id=1,name=null},{id=2,name=null},{id=3,name=c}]
List 2 = [{id=1,name=a},{id=2,name=b}]
```

After the merge, it should be [{id=1,name=a},{id=2,name=b},{id=3,name=c}]

```
Case 1 : 
List 1 = [{id=1,name=null}]
List 2 = [{id=1,name=a},{id=2,name=b}]
```

After the merge, it should be [{id=1,name=a},{id=2,name=b}]

My code:

```
 for (Object ObjofList1: list1) {
             List<DummyObject> do = new ArrayLIst();
            SomeObject sm = list2.stream()
                    .filter(list2object -> list2object.getId().equals(ObjofList1.getId()))
                    .findAny()
                    .orElse(ObjofList1);
                          do.add(dealerSalesTempObject);
          
        }
```

It is working fine if `list2` has more elements in it, but if `list1` has more element then we won't be able to merge because of less iteration.

My question is i don't want to see which one is shorter or longer but at last all objects should be in one list..

Comment: Is it relevant whether list 1 is merged into list 2 or could it be the other way round, i.e. could you make the longer of the 2 list 2 and the shorter list 1? Do you want the merge to happen in-place, i.e. make changes to one list, or would you want a "merged" copy of the lists?

Comment: My question is i don't want to see which one is shorter or longer but at last all objects should be in one list..

Comment: Note that your code wouldn't even compile, i.e. `do` is a reserved keyword and `dealerSalesTempObject` isn't defined - please post a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I join two lists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189559/how-do-i-join-two-lists-in-java)

Comment: changed that @Thomas

Comment: "i don't want to see which one is shorter or longer" - in that case just rearrange the lists so that the longer one is list 2 and you should be done.

Comment: yes @Thomas that is the problem i want it in one short without checking the length

Comment: see also this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520046/how-to-merge-two-arraylists-without-duplicates

Comment: In your case, if there is a conflict between list1 and list2, two elements with the same id, you always should consider list2 element? or there is no difference?

Comment: i will consider that list which have some data in it after comparing with id

Comment: @kole I'm not sure about why you don't want to check the length and rearrange by length since it would just be 1 or a few lines. Sometimes shorter code is not better code since it's harder to understand and write (see your case as an example). Also it is not clear what "merging" does mean as you can see by all the questions and assumptions in the answers. Additionally it's not clear if order needs to be preserved and whether or not you want a fresh list containing the merge result or do it in-place.

Comment: i have just update the case 1 and case 2 example @Thomas can you look into it,, you will get what i am asking.

Comment: One thing you _could_ do: put the elements of list 1 into a (linked hash) map with id being the key. (1 simple loop or using a stream) Then iterate over list 2 and get the map elements by id. If you found one do your merge, if not just put the element into the map. (thats 1 other simple loop).

Comment: Yes, we can do that also. but just finding a way in stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have updated your question and mentioned the use case of merging objects with the same id into a single object. The way I can think of would be something like this:

```java
List<DummyObject> list3 = new ArrayList<>(
    Stream
        .concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            DummyObject::getId, 
            Function.identity(), 
            (a, b) -> {
                 // here you can merge a and b
            }
         ))
         .values()
    );
```

---

#### Old answer

No need for `Stream`s, a simple `SortedSet` is enough:

```
SortedSet<DummyObject> result = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(DummyObject::getId));
result.addAll(list1);
result.addAll(list2);
```

The `SortedSet` can be used when you don't want to override the `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods. Additionally the `result` is sorted by id.

If you need a `List` afterwards you can convert it easily back:

```
List<DummyObject> list3 = new ArrayList<>(result);
```

But using a `Set` may be more declarative, as it clearly indicates that no duplicates are available.

Comment: Here we are comparing one obejct..but two list is there... i am not sure.. how to compare with list.

Comment: @kole I don't quite understand what you mean? What do you mean with: *comparing one object but two list is there*, where are these lists? which object is compared?

Comment: @kole the Set uses the given comparator whenever elements are added, to determine the ordering and to enforce uniqueness.

Comment: @Lino List1 List2 ::: comparing one object at a time from list_1 or list_2 and saving it in 
List3.. but the concern is we dont know which one have more element in it. and we are iterating on random list...at last list1 and list 2 will be merged on condition

Comment: @kole My solution **does not care**. It works with any amount of elements. Have you tried it out?

Comment: ok so what i am saying as per your soulution object should be passed but from which list?


`SortedSet<DummyObject> result = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(DummyObject::getId));`

Comment: @kole that constructor accepts a `Comparator<DummyObject>` used to find out the *uniqueness* of a `DummyObject`. We first add all objects of `list1` by using `result.addAll(list1)` and the other call `result.addAll(list2)` adds all the objects of `list2` **BUT**, will check that an object with the same id does not already exists. Meaning the resulting `result` contains all unique objects. If you still don't understand, then I suggest you to look at the javadoc of `Set`, `SortedSet` and `TreeSet`, or generally the difference between `List` and `Set`

Comment: but what if i want to save also those things which is not present at all at list 1 but present in list2.. will that work?

Comment: @kole yes it will, for reference have a look at [`Set#addAll(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)). *Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this set if they're not already present*

Comment: nullpointer exception : ask :`SeerDataSalesWeightProcessor.main() FAILED [StockProcessData(id=23232, unContractedStock=34, contractedStock=null), StockProcessData(id=30000, unContractedStock=null, contractedStock=null)] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerExceptio` @Lino

Comment: @kole https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: one question @Lino By this we can achive that but we are not pasting one value to the object... for example merging means if object id = 1, name="null" from list 1 and object id=  1, name="a" from list 2 then after mergring the final output should be id=1 name= a in the new list

Comment: @kole Maybe with streams: `List<DummyObject> list3 = new ArrayList<>(Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toMap(DummyObject::getId, Function.identity(), (a, b) -> {/*your merge function*/})).values());` where you define a lambda to merge two objects (`a`, `b`) when they have the same id

Comment: @Lino Did the code as commented above... seems like promising to me

Comment: Can u put your comment in ans so that it can be ticked out

Answer (score 4):

Introducing Stream to such problem just makes things more complicated for no real reason. Based on your example you just want to create a Set containing elements from both Lists. Something like this would be the easiest way to achieve it:

```
Set<Object> resultSet = new HashSet<>(list1);
result.addAll(list2);
List<Object> resultList = new ArrayList<>(result); // optionally if u want a List
```

This solution assumes that your class implements `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods.

Comment: @Lino correct, added that to my answer just as you commented.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge these two lists using streams, and then use `distinct`, in order to remove duplicate elements, and finally reconvert it to a `list`:

```
Stream.concat(list1.stream(), list2.stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**NOTE:** you need to implement `equals` and `hashcode` in your `DummyObject`, it's required to remove the duplicated elements when generating the `Set`.

**HashCode and Equals for your case (Considering the infos in the comments):**

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    StockProcessData that = (StockProcessData) o;

    if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) return false;
    if (unContractedStock != null ? !unContractedStock.equals(that.unContractedStock) : that.unContractedStock != null)
        return false;
    return contractedStock != null ? contractedStock.equals(that.contractedStock) : that.contractedStock == null;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (unContractedStock != null ? unContractedStock.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (contractedStock != null ? contractedStock.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: there is no comparison with id

Comment: You're right, I will edit the answer.

Comment: @kole It will work if you add the hashcode and equals implementation in the DummyObject class, you can see the edits, I have also edited the streams.

Comment: @Lino I forget to add the second call of stream, I have edited the answer, Sorry

Comment: @Lino Thank you, It is better, I have edited the answer.

Comment: one more thing i dont have any int type in my class...id is in String format then how to overrise hash in it –

Comment: @kole There is no problem what is the type of your fields, you can generate an accurate hash and equals, you can generate the hashCode and equals automatically using your IDE.

Comment: it is giving nullpointer exception

Comment: `ask :SeerDataSalesWeightProcessor.main() FAILED
[StockProcessData(id=23232, unContractedStock=34, contractedStock=null), StockProcessData(id=30000, unContractedStock=null, contractedStock=null)]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: I think the problem is not related to the code above, I have tested it before posting the answer, maybe the generated hashCode or equals has some issues. I have edited the answer with hashCode and equals code for you.

Comment: one question @Ismail By this we can achive that but we are not pasting one value to the object... for example merging means if object id = 1, name="null" from list 1 and object id= 1, name="a" from list 2 then after mergring the final output should be id=1 name= a in the new list

Comment: @kole ahh, I see, I think you should specify this requirement in your question. Things will be different from there.